# Visual c++ 6.0: error C2065: 'PWR_CString' : undeclared identifier

Tags: visual-c++

This error for the following:  C:\software\CATS\includes\Commun\xml_transfer.cpp(1527) : error C2065: 'PWR_CString' : undeclared identifier

```
CString s1;                    // Empty string
```

I did include:"stdafx.h" , "resource.h"

Comment: Any clue what the PWR_ is?  There's surprisingly little on Google at first glance.

Comment: 2 other string classes are present, but neither do "CString"... usually an extesnion: "CStringRW"

Comment: I'd see if you can look in the libraries.  See if you have `#define PWR_CString CString` or something like that somewhere?

Comment: Can I force CString from the foundation classes for at least a methode or function?

Comment: I'm not sure how unless you wrap your own; CString doesn't have a base class I don't think.

Comment: The preprocessor strikes again.